Refcount management in custom Cython container
I am implementing a custom Python container, but I am not sure to fully understand the INCREF/DECEF rules. Could someone provide an example of a very simple container (maybe as simple as std::pair in C++)? I mostly need to check the refcount operations required:

when initially storing a value in the container;
when replacing a value in the container;
at dealloc-time.

Related to: How to check reference counting issues when doing direct manipulations of CPython objects?
